# GridView.count cross-axis spacing too big

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create columns of widgets. So, something like

```
Hello0                   Hello1    
Hello2                   Hello3
```

When I try

```
GridView.count(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    // mainAxisSpacing: 20,
    children: const [
      Text('Hello0'),
      Text('Hello1'),
      Text('Hello2'),
      Text('Hello3'),
    ])
```

I get the output below

[image: GridView Output]

Is there a way to tighten the spacing between the rows or does GridView put everything in a square?

Answer (score 1):

GridView.count calculate its height based on aspect ratio which is 1.0 by default, so its children has extra space.
Instead you can use gridDelegate

```
     GridView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisExtent: 80,
          ),
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          // mainAxisSpacing: 20,
          children: const [
            Text('Hello1'),
            Text('Hello2'),
            Text('Hello3'),
      ])
```